# CE 1.8.1 invoice mail event hook

Tags: event-observer, ce-1.8.1.0, email, invoice

I want to implement an pdf attachment to my invoice mail to the customer. I have a pretty good guess on how to do that, however this time I would like to solve the task with an event observer.

Not having worked much with Magento Observers before, I have some troubles figuring out which event to hook into.

What I need is an event which happens when the standard email is composed, so that I can simply attach my pdf copy of the invoice. Funnily enough all the helpful sites I found on the internet omit exactly on explaining that step in order to keep the tutorial generic or something.

Any hint about the event, or even better on a generic way to figure out the right event to use in any task, would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You ,you check this link http://bluehorse.in/blog/custom-invoice-pdf-attachment-with-invoice-email-to-admin.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. Looks like this one uses the rewrite approach, though. I might have to resort to that, so I appreciate the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afaik there is still no event in the while mailing system of magento. Neither in `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template` nor in `Mage_Core_Model_Email` therefore you have to do what Samir is part 3 to rewrite the sending class add your own event and register an observer on it or just rewrite the class and add your attachement directly.

You should checkout `Fooman_EmailAttachments`: https://github.com/fooman/emailattachments

@fooman adds the events here `app/code/community/Fooman/EmailAttachments/Model/Core/Email/Template/Mailer.php`

Comment: That'll do. Thanks for pointing me the way.

Answer (score 0):

1. check the modules if you can find there something like 'dispatch' or observer
2. to get an overview use the search from your ide with 'dispatch' or Observer
3. If you cant find anything you can create your own observer, and add the dispatch where you need it by overriding the Model(s) in your custom module

Comment: Thanks, I guess I shouldn't have expected a less effortful way to figure the events out. It's Magento after all ;)